# How do I get/set and get the number of seconds directly from/on a FILETIME structure?

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, x86

> How do I set and get the number of seconds directly from a FILETIME structure?

Without using any API, I want to get/set the number of seconds from/on a FILETIME structure.

Is this possible?

I've tried juggling with some math on how to do it, but I've not come up with a formula yet.

Comment: Number of seconds from what epoch? For example, are you trying to get a Unix timestamp?

Comment: I'm trying to get the number of seconds corresponding to the file create time - the FILETIME structure contains this file create time

Comment: The problem is number of seconds from when? FILETIME records time starting at January 1, 1601 in 100 nanosecond increments. On the other hand, Unix-based systems records time in seconds from January 1, 1970. Excel and spreadsheets use a different starting time. NTP uses a different starting time. Everybody uses different starting times because no one seems to be able to agree on the best staring time to use.

Comment: why **Without using any API** ? however look for `RtlTimeToSecondsSince1970` and `RtlTimeToSecondsSince1980` this api convert `FILETIME` (this is the same as `LARGE_INTEGER`) to seconds. if not want use this api - copy it asm code - it very short and simply

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

> A file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 A.M. January 1, 1601 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290.aspx

To convert the structure into a 64-bit value, simply combine both parts to a __int64 and then integer divide by 10.000.000 (1 second has 1 billion nanoseconds, or 1E9; therefore 100-ns resolution is 1/100th of that or 1E7).

```
FILETIME timeFile;
__int64 Time = (__int64) timeFile.dwHighDateTime << 32 | timeFile.dwLowDateTime;
int TimeSec = Time / 10000000;
```

You can use ULARGE_INTEGER and access it via .QuadPart of that union but Microsoft also suggests to use __int64 or ULONGLONG. 64-bit numbers are a bit messy in .

---

If you need the value of Seconds as a fraction regarding Minute, use modulo 60. Same applies to minute and hour, but beware that FILTETIME is UTC not local time. To extract date, month and year gets a bit tricky not it doesn't sound like to want that.